# Javascript : optional parameters in function

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this :

```js
function concatenate(a, b, c) {
    // Concatenate a, b, and c
}
```

How do I handle those calls ?

```js
x = concatenate(a)

x = concatenate(a, b)

x = concatenate(a, c)
```

How can I make my function aware of the parameter I gave to it ?

Comment: Use an array as parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any unfilled argument will be `undefined`.

`concatenate(a, c)` is equivalent to `concatenate(a, b)`. You cannot pass the third parameter without passing the second; but you can pass `undefined` (or `null`, I suppose) explicitly: `concatenate(a, undefined, c)`.

In the function, you can check for `undefined` and replace with a default value.

Alternately, you can use an object argument to imitate keyword arguments: `concatenate({a: a, c: c})`.

Comment: Ok this is what I thought, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Just use `arguments` array-like object:

```
function concatenate() {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    result += arguments[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from ES6/ES2015 on you can do similar as in php:

```
function concatenate(a, b = false, c = false) {
    // Concatenate a, b, and c
}
```

for the older versions, you can do:

```
function concatenate(a, b, c) {
   if( typeof b !== 'undefined' && typeof c !== 'undefined') {
    // code when a, b and c are defined
   } else if ( typeof b !== 'undefined' && typeof c == 'undefined') {
    // code when a and b are defined
   } else {
   // code
   }

}
```

I am sure there is a better approach too, but should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the ES6 [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax to get an array of arguments. Then simply `join` its items to retrieve the concatenated string.

```
concatenate(a);
concatenate(a, b);
concatenate(a, c);

function concatenate(...args){
  // for old browsers
  // `...args` is an equivalent of `[].slice.call(arguments);`
  return args.join('');
}
```